^C characters appearing in the VS Code terminal, even without pressing Ctrl+C
enter image description hereI'm experiencing frequent ^C characters appearing in the VS Code terminal whenever i run java or c files, even without pressing Ctrl+C. This disrupts workflow and makes it difficult to use the terminal effectively. It start to pop-up in second run of a java or c program.
I have already reinstalled the Java Development Kit (JDK), VS Code itself, and all extensions.
